# How to Increment Multiple Numbers in a Sting?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am checking to see if two numbers match and if so just repeate a sting of numbers, if they dont not match i want to return the sting with all numbers incremented by 1.

```
=IF(AND(M5<>"",V5<>L5),M5, [increment the numbers] )
```

Given that:
M5= 9,8,7
V5 does equal L5

I want the output to be: 10,9,8

Comment: Use `M5+1` to increment 1.

Comment: You must misunderstand the question, maybe the error message will help:

"Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But '9,8,7' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be this

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(M5<>"",V5<>L5),M5, textjoin(",",,split(M5,",")+1)))
```

[image]

But note that it would try to split M5 if M5 is blank (giving an error) or V5=L5 so maybe try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(M5<>"",V5=L5),textjoin(",",,split(M5,",")+1),M5))
```

Comment: Fantastic solution, thank you so much the first one did run into the error as you suspected but the second worked like a charm.